# Get SharePoint calendar item RecurrenceData

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, caml

When I query my SharePoint 2013 calendar list item I get my event back, but for the RecurrenceData item the value just says V3RecurrencePattern.

How do I get the *actual* pattern that was set?  I'm not looking to get each instance of the item.  I really just want the recurrence data.

Answer (score 0):

You need `<DateRangesOverlap>` for that.

Try with this

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
string queryString =
@"
    <Where>
        <DateRangesOverlap>
        <FieldRef Name=""EventDate""/>
        <FieldRef Name=""EndDate""/>
        <FieldRef Name=""RecurrenceID""/>
        <Value IncludeTimeValue=""TRUE"" Type=""DateTime"">
        <Now/>
        </Value>
        </DateRangesOverlap>
    </Where>
    <OrderBy>          
    <FieldRef Name=""EventDate"" Ascending=""TRUE""/>      
    </OrderBy>
";
query.Query = queryString;
query.ExpandRecurrence = true;
```

Reference http://sharepointchan.blogspot.hr/2011/10/situation-i-want-to-get-all-calendar.html